# Does wrapping a pointer in shared_ptr guarantee it will be deleted if I continue to use the raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a hash table generated at runtime, populated by global variables.

```
inline A* global1 = new A();
inline A* global2 = new A();
inline A* global3 = new A();

std::map<A*, int> createMap() {
     return std::map<A*, int>({{global1, 1}, {global2, 2}, {global3, 3}});
}
```

I want to add new entries to `map` during runtime, meaning that I'll have to create new pointers to `A`.

```
void doStuff(std::map<A*, int>& map) {
    A* runTimeValue = new A();
    map[runTimeValue] = 4;
}
```

However this opens up the program to memory leaks as I'll have to worry about deleting `runTimeValue` when the map object finally goes out of scope and is deleted. I considered switching the map to `std::map<std::shared_ptr<A>, int>` but working with `std::shared_ptr<A>` is difficult as it has many different subclasses.

One solution I had was to wrap `runTimeValue` in a shared_ptr so that it can automatically be deleted, and then continue using the raw pointer.

```
void doStuff(std::map<A*, int>& map) {
    A* runTimeValue = new A();
    std::shared_ptr<A> temp(runTimeValue);
    map[runTimeValue] = 4;
}
```

Would this work? Do I need to store a reference to `temp` till the map goes out of scope? Is there a better way of dealing with a mix of global and run time pointers where run time ones have to be deleted but globals do not?

Edit, example of "program" in use:

```
inline A* global1 = new A();
inline A* global2 = new A();
inline A* global3 = new A();

int main() {
    while(true) {
        std::map<A*, int> map = createMap();
        doStuff(map);
        doStuff(map);
        doStuff(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure `doStuff` removes the `runTimeValue` from the `map` before it returns.

Comment: Using the raw pointer that is being managed by a *smart pointer* is fine (and normal) BUT the *smart pointer* MUST live longer than the raw pointer. You probably don't want a `std:shared_ptr`though but a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Well isn't that interesting. Inline variables. Never seen or used one of those before. Time to do some reading.

Comment: The use of `inline` variables here is redundant. You have a single C++ file. Try breaking your program into little classes. Each class should do a specific thing. Have `main()` tie it all together.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just do `std::map<A, int>`?

Comment: It would seem that my pathological hatred of global variables has blinded me to the existence of and need for `inline` variables. I can probably go to my grave without using one and feel fulfilled, but it's nice to know I have the option if I find a use case that calls for this.

Comment: Tip: never use the `new` operator to allocate memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a bit betwixt and between with this.  What you are proposing won't end well.  Assuming that you actually *need* a map of pointers...

If the map has sole ownership of the objects contained within it, use `std::map<std::unique_ptr <A>, int>`.  If it shares ownership with other parts of your code, use `std::map<std::shared_ptr <A>, int>`.

Then, either way:

- objects won't go away unexpectedly while still present in your map
- objects will be cleaned up (or their reference count decremented) when you remove them from your map

For your global objects, you can create them with `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` as appropriate, rather than using `new`.  Then they can be managed the same way as everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

If you use a smart pointer, then ensure that smart pointer 'owns' that memory from the outset. C++ is fond of the RAII concept.

I think you want a `unique_ptr` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

That is, just a smart point to ensure the memory is deleted.

In general, always use smart pointers over raw pointers. This makes ownership clearer. But you're allowed to expose it as a raw pointer (*A) when you need to. But let the smart pointer clean it up.